# Display just the top row numbers from UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

HI.

I am developing an iphone app where i just want to use numbers from the iphone keypad.  I am using the UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation keyboard, and ideally just want to display the keys of 0-9 from the top row of this keyboard.

Is there any way to do this, like change the position of the keyboard so that only the top row is displayed?

thanks
Kim

Answer (score 1):

did you try`UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` ?

Comment: forgot to say without the "done" button on keyboard you may need to post a UITextFieldDidChange notification to close the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't approach it this way, since you would also hide the "Done" button to dismiss the keyboard. In any way, this would look like a bad hack.

Why not making your own keyboard control which looks and acts exactly what you want it to do? That would seem to be the clean way to do it to me.

Answer (score 0):

HI, yes i tried UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad, but it takes up too much real estate on the screen, i have decided to build my own simple number pad.

thanks
Kim